# Access AWS step function error in lambda (Python) code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, catch-block

I used this link to include the previous state and error details in the "catch" block for a state in AWS step function :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html#input-output-resultpath-catch

And I am able to see them both, but how do I access the error details in the lambda function that the next step points to?

[image]

I could get the previous step input using the event['Input'] but the error is not available. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your state machine definition? It's hard to give an answer without seeing your code.

Comment: Its huge and I should not be sharing the code here. But I have used what is there in the link in the catch block, with next pointing to a lambda step. I need to access the error block in the lambda step

Answer (score 0):

As you can't share your state machine, I am assuming that you just simply want to pass the error message to the next step(like lambda etc).

```
        {
    "Comment": "A Catch example of the Amazon States Language using an AWS Lambda Function",
    "StartAt": "HelloWorld",
    "States": {
        "HelloWorld": {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:123456789:function:mytestfunction",
        "Catch": [
            {
            "ErrorEquals": ["States.TaskFailed"],
            "Next": "ReservedTypeFallback"
            }
        ],
        "End": true
        },
        "ReservedTypeFallback": {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:123456789:function:catcherror",
        "End": true
        }
    }
    }
```

The above state machine looks like this

[image]

**mytestfunction** lambda produces the error which gets carry forwarded to the next step **ReservedTypeFallback**

Below is the code for **catcherror** lambda

```
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        print(event)
        error_message = event.get('Cause')
        print(f'just printing the failure cause of earlier lambda {error_message}')
```

Produces the following message when my state machine executes:
[image]